# Outport/outportb in C vs TransmitCommChar in C++

Tags: c++, c, c++builder

I have a source code of a DOS program that controls a fuel injection device. I want to rewrite it to make it work under Windows. The DOS program initializes communication:

```
void port_initialization()
{
outportb(port+3,0x9F);
outport(port,speed);
outportb(port+3,0x1F);
outportb(port+1,0);
outportb(port+4,0);
outportb(port+2,7);
}
```

And in header:

```
int port=COM1,speed=6;
```

I assume that speed 6 is some internal device setup which will set the baud rate to certain value. I want to send the same thing in windows 7 (using c++ builder). I know direct hardware access is no longer supported and I want to work my way around it.
Here is a sample code I have in mind:

```
void port_initialization()
{
HANDLE hCom;
DCB dcb;
BOOL fSuccess;
hCom = CreateFile("COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200;   //These are sample values, I will use an oscilloscope to read real ones
dcb.ByteSize = 8;
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

TransmitCommChar(hCom,0x9F);
TransmitCommChar(hCom,6);
TransmitCommChar(hCom,0x1F);
TransmitCommChar(hCom,0);
TransmitCommChar(hCom,0);
TransmitCommChar(hCom,7);
}
```

Now my main question is - can a WIN32 TransmitCommChar replace the DOS outport/outportb in a way I replaced it? Can you suggest a better way to achieve it?

Thank you

Comment: Note that the old DOS code uses `port+x` where `x` is different. It writes to different registers to set up the serial port, it doesn't write all those bytes to the actual serial port. I suggest you learn how the old DOS "ports" (which is not the same as e.g. a serial port) works.

Comment: The outport commands are more like your `dcb.BaudRate = ...` and so on than the `TransnmistCommChar(...)`. Like Joachim says, you need to find the meaning of those bits, and set the `dcb` values accordingly. Some info here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/8250_UART_Programming (which, if you go to the section of "divisor latch bytes" says you need 19200 bps)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helped a lot. If I read well its 19200 baudrate, 8 bits, even parity, 2 stop bits, no interrupts, no mcr. What is a bit unclear is the double port+3 -I guess first one turns DLAB on to set the Baud rate and the second sets the actual transmission parameters?